# Varnish - Error 503 Backend fetch failed

Tags: varnish, magento2.2.2

I getting this error how can i do? i try to editing many time but still not work.

> Error 503 Backend fetch failed
>   Backend fetch failed
>
> Guru Meditation:
>   XID: 35

Varnish cache server

My CentOS 7: /etc/varnish/varnish.params

> # Varnish environment configuration description. This was derived from
>   # the old style sysconfig/defaults settings
>
> # Set this to 1 to make systemd reload try to switch VCL without restart. RELOAD_VCL=1
>
> # Main configuration file. You probably want to change it. VARNISH_VCL_CONF=/etc/varnish/default.vcl
>
> # Default address and port to bind to. Blank address means all IPv4
>   # and IPv6 interfaces, otherwise specify a host name, an IPv4 dotted
>   # quad, or an IPv6 address in brackets.
>   # VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS=192.168.1.5 VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=80
>
> # Admin interface listen address and port VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1 VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=6082
>
> # Shared secret file for admin interface VARNISH_SECRET_FILE=/etc/varnish/secret
>
> # Backend storage specification, see Storage Types in the varnishd(5)
>   # man page for details. VARNISH_STORAGE="malloc,1024M"
>
> # User and group for the varnishd worker processes VARNISH_USER=varnish VARNISH_GROUP=varnish
>
> # Other options, see the man page varnishd(1) DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s
>   malloc,1024m -p thread_pool_min=5 -p thread_pool_max=500 -p
>   thread_pool_timeout=300 -p http_resp_hdr_len=65536 -p
>   http_resp_size=98304 -p workspace_backend=98304"

update:

1) Yes, the vcl file generated by Magento.

2)

> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*             LISTEN      4338/varnishd
>
> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6082          0.0.0.0:*             LISTEN      4337/varnishd
>
> tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                 LISTEN      4338/varnishd
>
> tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                  LISTEN      3905/httpd

3) i in vcl edited added http:// beacuse when i only /pub/health_check.php will be 503, but added http:// the theme look like something wrong no css.

> .probe = {. 
>   url = "http://example.com/pub/health_check.php";

4) i used this command

> curl -I -v --location-trusted 'http://example.com'

show this, but i dont know working or not working, beacuse the var/page_cache/ directory is not empty. the mage-tags file still here.

> < X-Magento-Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache,no-store
>
> X-Magento-Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate,no-cache, no-store < Age: 0 Age: 0 <
>
> X-Magento-Cache-Debug: MISS
>
> X-Magento-Cache-Debug: MISS

Comment: you can not connect to backend. let's edit file /etc/varnish/default.vcl. 
Find line .url = "/pub/health_check.php", then change it .url = "/"; or .url = "/health_check.php";

Answer (score 4):

After compared with the /etc/varnish/default.vcl, I found after removing the **.probe** section in the backend default can solve this. Still wondering why the probe caused this

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/pub/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}
```

to

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
}
```

**Updated:**

Just change the following line:

```
.url = "/pub/health_check.php";
```

to

```
.url = "/health_check.php";
```

solved the problem, refer to this article 
https://www.sohaib.com/magento-2-12-varnish-error-503-backend-fetch-failed-solved-php-7-1-nginx-varnish-5-x/

Answer (score 1):

There are some possibilities to your error. I follow this tutorial (Solution 2) and successfully fix the error: https://magentip.com/magento-2-error-503-backend-fetch-failed-with-varnish-cache/

**1. Length of cache tags used by Magento exceed Varnish’s default value**

We will change `http_resp_hdr_len` value in Varnish configuration file. (Maximum length of any HTTP backend response header

The path to varnish configuration file is

-Ubuntu: /etc/default/varnish

-Centos 6 : /etc/sysconfig/varnish

-Centos 7: /etc/varnish/varnish.params

change the `http_resp_hdr_len` value (located in line 101 after `thread_pool_max` ) to

```
-p http_resp_hdr_len=70000 \
```

Also, change `http_resp_size` to

```
-p http_resp_size=100000 \
```

**2. Wrong health_check.php location in Varnish config file**

Go to Varnish configuration file (/etc/varnish/default.vcl) and find these lines

```
.probe = {
    .url = "/pub/health_check.php";
```

Change it to

```
.probe = {
    .url = "/health_check.php";
```

Comment: Changing the http_resp_hdr_len and http_resp_size in the init systemd configuration (/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service) worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"Error 503 Backend fetch failed" errors usually mean two things:

- Varnish is not able to fetch the response from Magento due to configuration issues
- There is an issue on Magento side. Magento sends 5xx HTTP response code.

### Varnish configuration issues

There are bunch of configuration issues, but most common are:

- default default.vcl file is used. Make sure you take the vcl file generated by Magento
- wrong backend specified in vcl file. Check the port and ip address specified in vcl file. I found `netstat -tnulp` useful tool to check the running services and their ports
- Your Magento instance is not in web_root. Check every relative path in vcl file and add corresponding prefixes(health check file, media files...).

You need to restart varnish after every change.

### Magento related issues

Usually, they are about some file permissions. In order to find exact issue, you need to skip varnish and visit the web server directly - http://your_domain.com:{web_server_port}/. Then you can turn on Magento developer mode in console using `./bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer` command and uncomment `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` line in `app/bootstrap.php`. After all these actions you should see the exact error message

Comment: I updated original post 1,2,3,4, please check,thank you

Comment: You have magento2 chunk in URL. Just add magento2/ prefix to all relative paths in vcl file. E.g. probe_url = domain.com/magento2/pub/health_check. Also, make sure you switch page cache to varnish in magento admin panel

Comment: but added http:// the theme look like something wrong no css. And no, my magento in public_html , domain.com/magento2 <-is for exsample. 
What is your mean? switch page cache to varnish in magento admin panel ?  is Cache Management? thank you

Comment: sorry what is switch page cache to varnish in magento admin panel ? is Cache Management? thank you

Comment: The setting is located in Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Full Page Cache. There is no need to specify http before paths. Instead, it should be the relative path to Magento.

Comment: i still getting 503..how can i do?thank you

Comment: Please check all paths in vcl file. Also, few tools might help you: 1 - varnishlog cli command allows to debug varnish requests more deeply; 2 -  varnishadm debug.health to debug the backend health status https://varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/BackendPolling#SHMlog

Comment: Hi, i added http in url, beacuse i add path :/home/XXX/public_html/pub/health_check.php"; is 503, but url:http sometime error 503 too, i dont know how happend. i saw it: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/varnish/tshoot-varnish-503.html <- but not work for me. my install varnish step is this https://www.tecmint.com/install-varnish-cache-web-accelerator/ <-

Comment: You need relative (not absolute) path. E.g. if your doc_root is on /home/xxx/public_html/ and path to health check is /home/xxx/public_html/magento/pub/health_check.php - you need to specify /magento/pub/health_check.php and restart varnish

Comment: yes,but my magento file in /home/xxx/public_html/. and how can i fix 503? beacuse this not work for me : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/varnish/tshoot-varnish-503.html